# Emulate memory-mapping of a game console, access different locations based on the address provided

Tags: c++, low-level, emulation, memory-mapping

I am implementing an emulator for an old game console, mostly for learning purposes.

This console maps roms, and a lot of other things, to regions within its address space. Certain locations are also mirrored so that multiple addresses can correspond to the same physical location. I would like to emulate this, but I am not sure what would be a good approach to do so (and also have no idea what this process is called, hence this somewhat generic question).

One thing that does work is a simple, unordered map. Have it contain absolute addresses and the corresponding pointers to my data structures. This way, I can easily map everything I need into the system's address space. The problem with this approach is that, it's obviously a memory hog. Even with small roms, I end up with close to ten million entries, thanks to the aforementioned mirroring. Surely, this can't be the rigth thing to do?

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:

To provide some details as to how exactly I am doing this:

The system in question is, of course, the SNES. Using [this wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Super_NES_Programming/SNES_memory_map#LoROM) as my primary resource, I implemeted what I mentioned above as follows:

- Create a `std::unordered_map<uint32,uint8_t*> mMemoryMap;`
- Check whether the rom is LoRom or HiRom
- For each byte in the rom

  - Calculate the address where it should be mapped and emplace both the address and a pointer to said byte in the map
  - If the section needs to be mirrored somewhere else, repeat the above
- This will be applied to anything else I need to make available, such as video- or system-memory

If I now want to access anything within the address space, I can simply use the address the system would use internally.

Comment: I think you should add code for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that for contiguous addresses the physical locations are also contiguous, within certain blocks of memory or "chunks". That is, if the address 0x0000 maps to 0xFF00, then 0x0004 maps to 0xFF04.

[image]

If they work like that, then you can make a list that contains the information of those chunks. Say:

```
struct Chunk
{
   int addressStart, memoryStart, size;
}
```

The chunks may be ordered by the addressStart, so you can find out the correct chunk you would need for any address. This requires you to iterate the list, but if you have only a few chunks this may be acceptable.

Comment: Such an obvious solution and yet I didn't see it at all. Very satisfied with the results. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use simple maps (which even with ranges can grow to large sizes) you can instead use a more intelligent map.

For instance if the console maps `0x10XXXX` through `0x1FXXXX` all to the same `0x20XXXX` you can design a structure which holds that repetition (start `0x100000` end `0x1FFFFF` repeat `0x010000` although you may want to use a bitmask rather than repeat).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently in the same boat as you and doing an NES emulator for learning purposes. The complete memory map is declared as an array of pointers to bytes. Each pointer can point into another array, which allows me to have pointers to the same data in the case of mirroring.

```
byte *memoryMap[cpuMemSize];
```

I iterate over the addresses that repeat and map them to point to the bytes in the following array. The ram array is the memory that gets mapped 4 times across the CPU's memory map.

```
byte ram[ramSize];
```

The following code goes through the RAM array and maps it across the CPU memory map 4 times.

```
// map RAM 4 times to emulate mirroring
mem_address memAddr = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
{
    for (mem_address ramAddr = 0; ramAddr < ramSize; ++ramAddr.value)
    {
        memoryMap[memAddr.value++] = &ram[ramAddr.value];
    }
}
```

You can then write the a value to the 256th byte using something like this, which would of course be propagated to the other parts of the memory map since they point to the same byte in memory:

```
*memoryMap[0x00ff] = 10;
```

I haven't really tested this and want to do some more testing with regard to CPU cache use and performance. I was clearly out searching for other ways of doing this when I stumbled on your question and figured I'd put in my (unverified) two cents. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Most of the time guest code running on your emulated NES will do most of its loads/stores on normal memory where contiguous addresses are contiguous in physical RAM, and using the same mapping of memory I would assume.  But the solution you chose doesn't allow for any extra efficiency, and adds an extra level of indirection for every memory access, done separately for each byte

Comment: If you compile your emulator for a 64-bit system, every byte of emulate RAM take 4x 8-byte pointers, or a factor of 32 space overhead.  This is fine for NES on a 3 to 4GHz CPU with more fast per-core L2 cache than NES had RAM (including typical cartridges), but is definitely in the realm of hilariously inefficient.  Consider that the MMU hardware in a CPU maps virtual address to physical with a page table that takes a ~8 bytes per 4k page mapped.

Comment: I guess you need finer granularity than 4k pages, but if you wanted to make it more complex + efficient, you could check for special addresses, and otherwise access emulated physical RAM through one of 4 pointers to the same array.  (Or just mask off some address bits of guest addresses after checking if they're MMIO addresses or otherwise special.  Then use them directly as an index to your physical array.  If the 4 mappings aren't power-of-2 sized, then it might not be that simple, but wrapping around with modulo a compile-time constant is also fairly efficient.

Comment: This is precisely why I've been looking for/playing around with other ideas for doing this mapping. I realize it has indirection and doesn't pack the data in a cache-friendly way, but I figured I'd toss the approach here anyways since it would be "ok" for a low-end system like the NES.

Comment: I mentioned cache not because this is cache-unfriendly, just wasteful overall.  And to make the point of how powerful modern CPUs are, so they do have enough cache to handle this.  But anyway, don't you still need to check for "special" addresses that are actually MMIO registers?  You can do that check on the full address, then mask off the high bits of the `memAddr` to get a `ramAddr`, right?  Or at least use some bits of the `memAddr` to index a table of pointers to blocks of RAM, like a page table, assuming that some power of 2 block size evenly divides your RAM space.

Comment: I mentioned the cache because I spent a lot of time looking at how to take advantage of CPU prefetch and caching for a entity component system for a game engine. As for this, I want to figure out a way to map the memory effectively without resorting to to a chain of if/else if blocks.

Comment: So there aren't any special MMIO addresses that trigger some special action and have to be handled differently from a load or store?  And would it work to use `&` to clear some high bits and leave you with a RAM address?

Comment: Yep, there's MMIO which I haven't gotten to quite yet. Wasn't sure how I was going to tackle the interaction with IO via mem mapping, I have some (probably naiive) ideas. I've found some good resources from other emulator authors so I'm going to RTFM and keep at it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If all the MMIO addresses are within some range, then that's one quick check before doing the "normal" thing.  It's ok if there's some normal memory in that range mixed with the MMIO addresses, sort that out only in the special case when code is accessing that memory.  You could use a bitmap to check if an address is an MMIO address or not.  And only if it is, then look up a function pointer from a hash table for a handler for it or something...  But in the normal case, your first check finds it's definitely not MMIO, then you do the simple fast-path thing.